# Azure AD B2C, Sendgrid - The requestor's IP Address is not whitelisted

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, sendgrid, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, sendgrid-api-v3

I have integrated Send grid with the Azure AD B2C using Custom policies for sending the OTP codes.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#create-azure-ad-b2c-policy-key

The send grid is enabled with the IP whitelisting, So I am getting the error ***"The requestor's IP Address is not whitelisted"*** while sending OTP from AD B2C.

Logs from App Insights

```
outerMessage
Exception Message:Original Exception type:HttpResponseException, responseContent:{"errors":[{"message":"The requestor's IP Address is not whitelisted","field":null,"help":null}]}, Exception Type:PolicyException, CorrelationID:xxxxxxx

details
[{"outerId":"0","message":"Exception Message:Original Exception type:HttpResponseException, responseContent:{\"errors\":[{\"message\":\"The requestor's IP Address is not whitelisted\",\"field\":null,\"help\":null}]}, Exception Type:PolicyException, CorrelationID:xxxxx","type":"System.Exception","id":"42573161"}]
```

Now I need to whitelist the IP address of AD B2C tenant, Please share how to get the IP address range of the AD B2C Tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [you can download Azure IP ranges right here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519).